# I am having trouble scraping a certain table from basketball reference

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

On basketball-reference, there's section of stats called Team Misc. Here's the url to an example of it:

https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/MIL/2023.html#all_per_minute-playoffs_per_minute

Anyways, using this code:

```
link = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/MIL/2023.html#all_per_minute-playoffs_per_minute"
page = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table_text = soup.find(id = "all_team_misc")
```

The last part of table_text looks like the following:

```html
<tbody><tr ><th scope="row" class="left " data-stat="player" >Team</th><td class="center " data-stat="wins" >41</td><td class="center " data-stat="losses" >17</td><td class="center " data-stat="wins_pyth" >35</td><td class="center " data-stat="losses_pyth" >23</td><td class="center " data-stat="mov" >3.22</td><td class="center " data-stat="sos" >-0.11</td><td class="center " data-stat="srs" >3.12</td><td class="center " data-stat="off_rtg" >113.8</td><td class="center " data-stat="def_rtg" >110.6</td><td class="center " data-stat="pace" >100.0</td><td class="center " data-stat="fta_per_fga_pct" >.254</td><td class="center " data-stat="fg3a_per_fga_pct" >.444</td><td class="center " data-stat="efg_pct" >.543</td><td class="center " data-stat="tov_pct" >13.0</td><td class="center " data-stat="orb_pct" >25.8</td><td class="center " data-stat="ft_rate" >.187</td><td class="center " data-stat="opp_efg_pct" >.516</td><td class="center " data-stat="opp_tov_pct" >10.6</td><td class="center " data-stat="drb_pct" >78.0</td><td class="center " data-stat="opp_ft_rate" >.179</td><td class="center " data-stat="arena_name" >Fiserv Forum</td><td class="center " data-stat="attendance" >506,491</td></tr>
<tr ><th scope="row" class="left " data-stat="player" >Lg Rank</th><td class="center " data-stat="wins" >2</td><td class="center " data-stat="losses" >29</td><td class="center " data-stat="wins_pyth" >6</td><td class="center " data-stat="losses_pyth" >6</td><td class="center " data-stat="mov" >6</td><td class="center " data-stat="sos" >21</td><td class="center " data-stat="srs" >6</td><td class="center " data-stat="off_rtg" >20</td><td class="center " data-stat="def_rtg" >3</td><td class="center " data-stat="pace" >11</td><td class="center " data-stat="fta_per_fga_pct" >23</td><td class="center " data-stat="fg3a_per_fga_pct" >4</td><td class="center " data-stat="efg_pct" >14</td><td class="center " data-stat="tov_pct" >18</td><td class="center " data-stat="orb_pct" >8</td><td class="center " data-stat="ft_rate" >28</td><td class="center " data-stat="opp_efg_pct" >1</td><td class="center " data-stat="opp_tov_pct" >30</td><td class="center " data-stat="drb_pct" >4</td><td class="center " data-stat="opp_ft_rate" >2</td><td class="center iz" data-stat="arena_name" ></td><td class="center " data-stat="attendance" >20</td></tr>
```

How can I extract just numerical data from here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas` to extract data without pain:

```
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/MIL/2023.html')
stats = dfs[2].dropna()  # the third table in the page and remove the last row
```

Output:

```
>>> stats
      Rk                  Player   Age   G    GS    MP   FG  FGA    FG%   3P  3PA    3P%  ...   FT  FTA    FT%  ORB  DRB  TRB  AST  STL  BLK  TOV   PF   PTS
0    1.0             Brook Lopez  34.0  57  57.0  1729  315  621  0.507  104  278  0.374  ...   94  122  0.770  111  260  371   70   27  139   77  145   828
1    2.0   Giannis Antetokounmpo  28.0  47  47.0  1554  532  988  0.538   38  141  0.270  ...  394  610  0.646  109  463  572  254   36   37  187  159  1496
2    3.0            Jrue Holiday  32.0  47  45.0  1552  345  747  0.462  112  297  0.377  ...  112  129  0.868   60  186  246  336   61   17  144   90   914
3    4.0           Grayson Allen  27.0  54  52.0  1491  183  412  0.444  106  262  0.405  ...   94  104  0.904   46  138  184  130   44   10   59   86   566
4    5.0            Jevon Carter  27.0  58  31.0  1306  162  375  0.432   91  218  0.417  ...   22   27  0.815   25  124  149  149   57   25   63  118   437
5    6.0            Bobby Portis  27.0  47  14.0  1258  281  563  0.499   58  170  0.341  ...   58   70  0.829  120  353  473   85   22   11   59   81   678
6    7.0         Pat Connaughton  30.0  41  25.0  1043  124  314  0.395   85  240  0.354  ...   17   28  0.607   35  173  208   53   30    5   25   44   350
7    8.0             George Hill  36.0  35   0.0   668   59  132  0.447   23   74  0.311  ...   34   46  0.739   13   54   67   89   19    3   27   41   175
8    9.0         Wesley Matthews  36.0  39   0.0   608   39  118  0.331   31   95  0.326  ...   17   20  0.850   30   57   87   20   17   10   15   55   126
9   10.0            Jordan Nwora  24.0  38   3.0   597   76  197  0.386   40  102  0.392  ...   37   43  0.860   29   88  117   38   12    7   34   34   229
10  11.0        MarJon Beauchamp  22.0  38   9.0   563   80  201  0.398   38  118  0.322  ...   21   29  0.724   34   56   90   26   18    4   36   59   219
11  12.0              Joe Ingles  35.0  25   0.0   563   53  140  0.379   38  111  0.342  ...   11   13  0.846    8   64   72   81   14    3   29   40   155
12  13.0         Khris Middleton  31.0  17   7.0   364   83  197  0.421   24   83  0.289  ...   41   44  0.932   10   55   65   67   11    3   34   36   231
13  14.0              A.J. Green  23.0  26   0.0   244   42   92  0.457   33   77  0.429  ...    4    4  1.000    4   24   28   12    5    0    7   24   121
14  15.0   Sandro Mamukelashvili  23.0  24   0.0   217   19   58  0.328    7   32  0.219  ...   12   18  0.667   18   38   56   16    4    5    9   19    57
15  16.0             Serge Ibaka  33.0  16   0.0   185   26   54  0.481    6   18  0.333  ...    8   13  0.615   15   29   44    4    2    7   11   23    66
16  17.0  Thanasis Antetokounmpo  30.0  25   0.0   101    4   19  0.211    0    4  0.000  ...    4    8  0.500    8   17   25    4    2    3    7   12    12

[17 rows x 28 columns]
```

You can also export the result as `dict` with `d = stats.to_dict('records')`.

Comment: I tried running what you wrote, but I got this error: "urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)>"